# How do we capture all container logs on google Vertex AI?

Tags: gcloud, google-ai-platform

I am having an endpoint for online predictions on AI platform (unified)
and only logs with [severity](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity) >= ERROR can be found..

Model was deployed using: `--enable-container-logging`

Logger code within container:

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger("MODULE_NAME")
module_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter("%(asctime)s — %(name)s — %(levelname)s — %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d — " "%(message)s")
module_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

**Query:** `resource.type="aiplatform.googleapis.com/Endpoint" resource.labels.endpoint_id="ENDPOINT_ID" resource.labels.location="us-central1"`

Two questions:

1. How do we make sure all logs logged by the container are logged and seen in the logs viewer?
2. What's that severity? how is it deduced by the console/platform?

Answer (score 4):

Answering myself:

1. [Container logs that are logged to stdout or stderr are captured by the gcloud logger](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging)
2. There isn't seem to be clear documentation but it seem that `stderr` logs are being interpreted to have Severity `ERROR` while stdout are `INFO`