# How to view and Interprete Vertex AI Logs

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

We have deployed Models in the Vertex AI endpoint.
Now we want to know and interpret logs regarding events
of Node creation, POD creation, user API call matric etc.

Is there any way or key by which we can filter the logs for Analysis?

Comment: [Vertex AI Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging) are well described in the documentation. Or maybe you are looking information about [Log Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview) Could you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As I believe VertexAI uses Container with Kubernetes. I wanted to view the time at which new Kubernetes pods are created. The amount of resources it occupied. No of running pods etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not specify your question I will provide quite a general answer which might help other members.

There is a Documentation which explains `Vertex AI` logging information - [Vertex AI audit logging information](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging).

> Google Cloud services write audit logs to help you answer the questions, "Who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud resources.

Currently `Vertex AI` supports 2 types of Audit Logs:

- [Admin Activity](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#admin-activity) audit logs

> Admin Activity audit logs contain log entries for API calls or other actions that modify the configuration or metadata of resources. For example, these logs record when users create VM instances or change Identity and Access Management permissions.

- [Data Access](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#data-access) audit logs

> Data Access audit logs contain API calls that read the configuration or metadata of resources, as well as user-driven API calls that create, modify, or read user-provided resource data.

Two others like `System Event logs` and `Policy Denied logs` are currently not supported in `Vertex AI`. In guide [Google services with audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services) you can find more information.

If you want to view audit logs, you can use `Console`, `gcloud` command or `API`. Depending on how you want to get them you should follow steps mentioned in [Viewing audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs). For example, if you would use `Console`, you will use [Log Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview).

Additional threads which might be helpful:

- [How do we capture all container logs on google Vertex AI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67584220/)
- [How to structure container logs in Vertex AI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892701/)

Answer (score 0):

For container logs (logs that are created by your model) you can't currently,
the entire log entry is captured by the Vertex AI platform and assigned as a string to the "message" field within the parent "jsonPayload" fields,
the answer above of @PjoterS suggests a workaround to that limitation which isn't easy in my opinion.
It would have been better if Vertex had offered some mechanism by which you could log directly to the endpoint resource from the container using their gcloud logging lib or better, unpack the captured log fields as sub fields to the "jsonPayload" parent field, or into "message"